# ScrapyJS Example From Official Github Not Running

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to write a small web parser that obtains the javascript code. For this purpose, I've tried *ScrapyJS* to extend Scrapy by Javscript.

I've followed the installation instructions on [the official repository](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash). 
Scrapy itself works fine, but the second example from scrapyJS (*Get HTML contents and a screenshot:*) not. So hopefully, my question will help others running into the same problem ;)

*My settings and the code is as follows (if needed):*

1. First, I installed scrapyJS via `sudo -H pip install scrapyjs`
2. Then, I run the following command: `sudo docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash`
3. Before, I changed the settings.py of my scrapy project. I added the following lines:

   `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware': 725,
   }
   DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
   HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'`
4. The full python code looks like this:

:

```
import json
import base64
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_result, meta={
            'splash': {
                'args': {
                    'html': 1,
                    'png': 1,
                    'width': 600,
                    'render_all': 1,
                }
            }
        })

    def parse_result(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        body = data['html']
        png_bytes = base64.b64decode(data['png'])
        print body
```

I get the following error:

```
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.json> (failed 1 times): 400 Bad Request
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.json> (failed 2 times): 400 Bad Request
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <POST http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.json> (failed 3 times): 400 Bad Request
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.json> (referer: None)
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <400 http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.json>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2016-01-07 14:08:16 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

So I actually don't know where the error is. Scrapy alone works.
If I add `SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050'`, I'll get a timeout error instead. Nothing is happening then. Localhost:8050 is neither working. Leaving SPLASH_URL empty resolves the error, but then I get the error above.

Comment: what happens when you set `SPLASH_URL` to `'http://localhost:8050'`?

Comment: try with cUrl and see what happens: `curl 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://www.google.com'`

Comment: with cURl as well, it times out. I am not the OP but I have the same problem. I wonder how so many people are using it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass non-zero 'wait' to render full webpage.

So just add 'wait': 0.5 and then it should work.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_result, meta={
        'splash': {
            'args': {
                'html': 1,
                'png': 1,
                'width': 600,
                'render_all': 1,
                'wait': 0.5
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you skipped this part?

> Install Docker.
>
> Pull the image:
>
> > $ sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash

http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/install.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've installed Docker as well as started the container with sudo docker run ...; I still get the error